# Não consigo criar uma feature na pasta src/test/java

Tags: java, eclipse

Estou tentando criar um arquivo feature em um projeto maven mas não aparece a opção file dentro do diretório: `src/test/java`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Tenho um outro computador com a mesma versão do eclipse e do java onde funciona.

Comment: Tenta verificar a versão do Eclipse? O suporte ao `Maven` é um plugin? Se for, verifica sua versão também.

Comment: Class, Interface, Enum são arquivos, Package é pasta. Já tentou pra ver se dá certo?

Answer (score -1):

Cara, muda a perspectiva do eclipse para Navigator: Window -> Show View -> Navigator assim você conseguirá criar o novo arquivo.